# Create file with latest git commit info during Bamboo build

Tags: git, shell, bamboo

I need to create a file with latest git commit info. I've added a new Command to Bamboo build cycle. See screenshot[image]

When I run a job, the error occurs:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

I think I need somehow to escape this command, but don't know how.
Can somebody help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the redirection isn't supported, you could:

- wrap the `git log -n 1 > version.txt` in a script and
- call that script in your Command